# How do I include the dependencies for google closure

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I run the very basic file:

```
goog.provide('test');

goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
goog.require('goog.json.Serializer');
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.ui.HoverCard');
goog.require('goog.positioning');
goog.require('goog.dom.dataset');
```

but I get

```
test.js:3: ERROR - required "goog.net.XhrIo" namespace never provided
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
```

on compiling with

```
java -d32 -client -jar compiler/compiler.jar --js compiler/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js --js test.js --warning_level=VERBOSE
```

how does it know to look for the goog libraries?

Edit:

I also tried using the online one at: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home and still get:

```
    JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.net.XhrIo" namespace never provided at line 3 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
^
JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.json.Serializer" namespace never provided at line 4 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.json.Serializer');
^
JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.dom" namespace never provided at line 5 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.dom');
^
JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.ui.HoverCard" namespace never provided at line 6 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.ui.HoverCard');
^
JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.positioning" namespace never provided at line 7 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.positioning');
^
JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR: required "goog.dom.dataset" namespace never provided at line 8 character 0 in test.js
goog.require('goog.dom.dataset');
```

Comment: this works fine when I use the closurebuilder, i will use that for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to remember that Google Closure is a *collection of tools*.

Though the tools are synergistic, Google has maintained a fair degree of independence between these tools. The Closure Compiler can work without the Closure Library, the Closure Library can work without the Closure Compiler. Both can work without Closure Templates, etc.

The closurebuilder Python scripts were made and included with  to provide some things the Closure Compiler lacked. Nowadays however, you should rarely have to use them.

The Closure Compiler fairly recently allowed wildcard expressions to solve this particular problem.

```
java -d32 -client -jar compiler/compiler.jar \
    --closure_entry_point=test               \
    --only_closure_dependencies              \
    --warning_level=VERBOSE                  \
    compiler/closure-library/**
```

Every file in `compiler/closure-library/` is examined to see whether it provides the necessary namespaces. Anything other files will not be included (`only_closure_dependencies`).

Comment: I've been struggling with this same issue over the weekend. What you describe makes sense, but I'm not sure how you got it from reading the documentation. That being said, running the sample command you provided above errors for me: "When only_closure_dependencies is on, you must specify at least one closure_entry_point"

Comment: @brianvaughn, yeah, Closure isn't what I would describe as beginner friendly like some other JS tools. And yeah, you need to add  `--closure_entry_point=test`, where `test` is the top level symbol.

Comment: I've made a little progress since leaving my last comment. Closure definitely feels more like a Java library than a JS one in terms of its toolchain and documentation. Thanks for sharing your thoughts though, it helped me past one sticking point. :)